# firefox extension puzzle

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

This is something that is puzzling the heck out of me, my code:

```
        var this_version=null;              
        try 

    {


// Firefox 4 and later; Mozilla 2 and later
        Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
        AddonManager.getAddonByID("Mf@mafiaafire.com", function(addon) {
           // alert("My extension's version is r" + addon.version);
           this_version = addon.version;
      });
    }
    catch (ex) {
        // Firefox 3.6 and before; Mozilla 1.9.2 and before
        var em = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/extensions/manager;1"]
                 .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIExtensionManager);
        var addon = em.getItemForID("Mf@mafiaafire.com");
        //alert("My extension's version is rr" + addon.version);
       this_version = addon.version;
    }
    alert("aa:"+this_version);

    /* #### End ### */


            if (prefManager.getCharPref("extensions.mafiaafire.quickfilter_ver") != this_version) 
                {



                    //prefManager.setCharPref("extensions.mafiaafire.quickfilter_ver",this.version);
                    alert("bb:"+this_version);
                    //gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab(prefManager.getCharPref("extensions.mafiaafire.quickfilter_ver_change_url"));    
                }
```

I am on FF 4, and the first alert is always giving me null and the second alert the correct version.

But if I take out the first alert, then the second alert is giving me null!!!!

It just does not make any sense.

Comment: Working with alerts normally means timing issues.

Comment: @epascarello, so how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is that the Firefox 4 code is *asynchronous*.

```
AddonManager.getAddonByID("Mf@mafiaafire.com", function(addon) {
  // alert("My extension's version is r" + addon.version);
  this_version = addon.version;
});
```

means, go get the version of this addon, and when you get it, let me know by calling this function here. When you get to the first alert, the addon manager hasn't gotten it yet. Since it takes a second or so before you click OK on the alert, it *does* have it by the time the second alert comes.

Comment: Aha! That makes sense!!! Now how do I solve that? Is there some kind of sleep or some way way to force it to wait?

Comment: I think it kind of depends what you actually want to use the version for. If you just wanted to alert it, you could put the alert in the callback function (like you did, but commented out). Presumably you actually want to use it in some other way, so this might be a case where you need to tell us a little more about what you're *really* doing..

Comment: Nothing really fancy, if version is not equal to the version already installed I want to open a page that says whats new with this version. But I think the user is going to be pretty upset if I do that everytime they use the browser...

Comment: I think the addon manager may have better ways of doing that, like it might automatically fire some event whenever an addon is upgraded, so you can just listen for that event. I could be imagining it but it's a very common thing that many addons do, so you might want to just look at how they do it...

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me as I took some time to ponder over it. I just moved the executing code further down the execution path and moved version checking code up... which delayed the time when each fired - works like a charm. I hope this helps others who are looking for the same solution. SO f***ing rocks!